# Javascript auth similar to Python auth?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get data from a rest api call and with python request and it is working. How can I do similar in JavaScript and Typescript? I will need it in my Angular2 application.

**Working Python script**
    import requests

```
url = "restapi"

r = requests.post(url,  auth=('user', 'password'))
print(r.text)
```

Comment: how it was? can you give a feedback?

Comment: I want to call an external rest api with angular. But I am getting error Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Ok, but this is not your question (that is a server configuaration not linked to angular).
First accept the answer and I will help you with this problem on a separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use http (provided with RxJS)

Your import:

`import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

Injected in your constructor:

`constructor(public http: Http) {}`

Your rest request method:

```
login(user:User,onNext: (response) => void) {
    this.http
        .post(BASE_URL+"/login",user)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(onNext,(e)=> console.error(`${e}`));
}
```

Note1: User is a typed json with just `{user:string, password:string}`

Note2: Please consider to do all the above in a `@Injectable()` Provider/Service, and the next step in your component (for beginning you can make everything in the same class)

Then use it like this

```
login(myUserJson,(result)=>{
     console.log(result);
     //proceed!...
})
```